# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

Riesel and Gohl show in *Some Calculations Related to Riemann's Prime Number Formula* that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\left(\int_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}-\ln 2\right)=\frac{1}{2\ln x}\sum_{n=1}^N \mu (n)+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}+\epsilon (x,N)$$
where
$$\epsilon (x,N)=-\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\ln x+C\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)\ln n}{n}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k}\arctan\frac{\ln x}{n\pi k}$$
where
$$C=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k}\arctan\frac{1}{\pi k}+\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm du}{u(e^{2u}-1)}-\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now, $\epsilon\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)=-2$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\int_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{\ln x}.$$

But how does one make sense of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)=-2$? Of course, it can be obtained *incorrectly* by just plugging $s=0$ in
$$\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n^s},\, \operatorname{Re}s\gt 1.$$

Comment: They use the result intensely here: http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html#theory

Comment: But this is only true under an additional assumption: "if we allow generalized summation".

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Can that result be made rigorous?

Comment: It seems that the link simply uses $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ at $s=0$, as you said. But this is not correct, since we need $Re(s)\ge 1$. Your link even writes $1/\zeta(0)$.

Comment: So, ultimately, is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)$ convergent?

Comment: It should diverge. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg) diverges, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n=0.$

Comment: I see that the similar problem involves some discussion of the Riemann hypothesis. You say $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)$ "should" diverge. Does that mean we don't know for sure?

Comment: $\mu(n)$ doesn't have a limit as $n$ goes to infinity, so of course the original series should diverge. That said, there are several ways to renormalize divergent series. One approach is to use a functional equation which provides an analytic continuation, like the one for $\zeta(s)$. Then since $\zeta(0)=-1/2$, the result follows.

Comment: Zeta function regularization was used here, as I see now, but different summation methods can produce different results. How can I confirm that the sum is really $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{\ln x}$ but not another function? Different values can be assigned to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)$.

Comment: @Wane I should be able to answer your question about the whole Riemann, Riesel&Göhl etc. stuff on math.se as well as on MO. However I'd like to talk to you about a thing or two, so please ping me if you're online again so I can create a chatroom.

Comment: @vitamin d Sure

Comment: @vitamin d I'm sorry it took me so long to respond. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @Wane Hi :) Please enter [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127683/wane-and-vitamind).